# how to multiply input value of each div with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several line of div with same id, i would like to multiply two input value of each div and display result in third input after changing value of val1 input or val2 input

html

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-9-10" id="commandligne">
    <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small" data-uk-grid-margin>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">
            <label for="inv1">P.U. (€)</label>
            <input type="text" name="prix-item[]" class="md-input val1"  id="inv1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">
            <label for="inv2">Qté (H)</label>
            <input type="text" name="qte-item[]" class="md-input val2" id="inv2" />
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">
            <label for="inv3">Total(€)</label>
            <input type="text" name="total-item[]" class="md-input val3" value="0" id="inv3" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS that doesnt work at all

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#commandligne input").keyup(multInputs);

       function multInputs() {
           var mult = 0;
           // for each row:
           $("div#commandligne").each(function () {
               // get the values from this div:
               var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
               var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
               var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
               $('.val3',this).val($total);
           });
       }
  });
```

Nothing happen when i change value of 2 input, then i have 0 error .

Here Jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/a66bgddu/1/

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: hi ! thx for your answer ! i have to increment each commandligne with js ? i'll try thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Consider Usage of `id` Attributes**

You are currently appending multiple elements with the same ID, which is not valid. `id` attributes by definition must be unique :

> The id global attribute **defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be
>   unique in the whole document.** Its purpose is to identify the element
>   when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
>   (with CSS).

If you need to target multiple elements, then consider using classes or `data-*` attributes to select them. Alternatively, you could track the number of "rows" and append the number after each ID and use the [jQuery "starts-with" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to target them:

**Ensuring Dynamic Elements Are Targeted**

Currently, your event handlers do not target any elements that may be added to the DOM in the future. You may want to consider using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function handle wiring up your events, which will target those that currently exist in the DOM and those that may be added in the future :

```
// Example using a class "command-row" as opposed to Id attributes
$(document).on('keyup',"div.command-row input",multInputs);
```

**Parse Your Values**

Since you are performing arithmetical operations on your values, you'll want to ensure that you are actually parsing the contents of your `<input>` elements as opposed to simply retrieving string versions of their values. You can do this using the [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function :

```
// Parse your values
var $val1 = parseInt($('.val1', this).val());
var $val2 = parseInt($('.val2', this).val());
// Get your total
var $total = $val1 * $val2
// Set your value
$('.val3',this).val($total);
```

**Example: Putting It All Together**

[image]

```js
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
  var ok = true;

  if (ok === true) {
    var html = [
      '<br/><br/>',
      '<div class="uk-grid  uk-margin-bottom"  data-uk-grid-margin>',
      '<div class="uk-width-medium-9-10 command-row">',
      '<div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small" data-uk-grid-margin>',
      '<div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">',
      '<label for="inv1">P.U. (€)</label>',
      '<input type="text" name="prix-item[]" class="md-input val1"  />',
      '</div>',
      '<div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">',
      '<label for="inv2">Qté (H)</label>',
      '<input type="text" name="qte-item[]" class="md-input val2"  />',
      '</div>',
      '<div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">',
      '<label for="inv3">Total(€)</label>',
      '<input type="text" name="total-item[]" class="md-input val3" value="0"  readonly/>',
      '</div>',
      '</div>',
      '</div>',
      '</div>'
    ].join('');

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;

    document.getElementById('testa').appendChild(div);
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', "div.command-row input", multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    // for each row:
    $("div.command-row").each(function() {
      // get the values from this div:
      var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
      var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
      var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
      $('.val3', this).val($total);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testa">
  <div class="uk-grid  uk-margin-bottom" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-9-10 command-row">
      <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small" data-uk-grid-margin>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">
          <label for="inv1">P.U. (€)</label>
          <input type="text" name="prix-item[]" class="md-input val1" />
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">
          <label for="inv2">Qté (H)</label>
          <input type="text" name="qte-item[]" class="md-input val2" />
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-medium-2-10">
          <label for="inv3">Total(€)</label>
          <input type="text" name="total-item[]" class="md-input val3" value="0" readonly/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="test" class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
  <div class="uk-width-1-1">
    <div id="form_invoice_services"></div>
    <div class="uk-text-center uk-margin-medium-top uk-margin-bottom">
      <a href="#" class="md-btn md-btn-flat md-btn-flat-primary" id="invoice_form_append_service_btn">Ajouter une ligne</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the fundamental issue that you are facing is that `id` attributes **MUST** be unique on a page in HTML.  Browsers are flexible about this and don't really complain about it if you have duplicates, but both JavaScript and jQuery are not.

In both cases (`getElementById` in JavaScript and `$("#aDuplicatedId")` in jQuery), the logic will only capture a single DOM node/jQuery object . . . specifically the first one that it encounters in the DOM that has the specified `id`.

To do what you are trying to do, consider using a common class that you can select on.  This will capture all instances and allow you to iterate through using your existing code.

Comment: so if i change #commandligne with .uk-grid, it will be ok ? i'll try this !

Comment: Base on the sample HTML that you included, it looks like that **should** work.  I'd still recommend making your `id`s unique anyway, though.   ;)